# CouchDB: How to get all documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, couchdb, couchrest

I am using CouchRest for Rails and I'm having problems understanding the documentation (or lack of it).

```
response = @db.save_doc( { :key => 'value', 'another key' => 'another value' } )

#doc = @db.get(response['id'])
doc = @db.get(:key => 'value')
```

After saving the doc, how do I get all the documents where the `key => 'value'` =

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a view where 'key' is your index. Then you can query that view.

Based loosely on the [docs](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest/wiki/couchrest-core):

```
@db.save_doc({
      "_id" => "_design/my_view", 
      :views => {
        :test => {
          :map => "function(doc){ emit(doc.key,null)}"
          }
        }
      })
    puts @db.view('my_view/test', 'key' => 'value')['rows'].inspect
```